# Subquery where I can count number of times a name appears from the first query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

This is the current code I have:

```
select Name, ECU, Identifier, Value, Max(Filetime) as "Filetime"
from dbo.view_1
where ECU='EBS7' and Identifier='88' and Value='2459579' or identifier ='87' and Value='2431629'
group by Name, ECU, Identifier, Value
ORDER BY
    MAX(Name) ASC
```

This is the result I get: [image: Result of query]

I would like some kind of subquery or something that counts how many times a name appears. We can see that Agon appears two times and Apollo Akka appears only once.

Any tips on what I should write?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...) Your AND/OR usage may need some parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about MySQL (which product are you actually using?), but in MS-SQL this

```
ORDER BY MAX(Name) ASC
```

would not even compile.  You can't order by a column which isn't in the SELECT list.

If you want to get your original resultset, with the name's frequency in the set itself, and you're using MS-SQL, you could use a CTE:

```
WITH theset AS 
(select Name, ECU, Identifier, Value, Max(Filetime) as "Filetime"
from dbo.view_1
where ECU='EBS7' and Identifier='88' and Value='2459579' or identifier ='87' and Value='2431629'
group by Name, ECU, Identifier, Value)

SELECT set.*,CountNames.NameCount
FROM
    theset set
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Name,Count(*) AS NameCount FROM theset GROUP BY Name) CountNames
ON set.Name=CountNames.Name
```

Comment: I'm using ms sql 2014 version. The `Order BY max(name) asc`actually works. Since i have a group by i need to have somekind of aggregating function to use order by. This way the list is sorted by names.

Thanks, i will try your code!

Comment: ORDER BY Max(Name) may "work" in that it compiles, but it's meaningless.  When Name is already in the GROUP BY clause, Name will axiomatically always = MAX(Name) for every member of the set.  ORDER BY Max(Name) is equivalent to ORDER BY (Name), and is confusing, so I'd recommend taking it out.  Let me now whether the CTE code works

Comment: Compile error at `Select set.*, CountNames.NameCount` and at `ON set.Name=CountNames.Name` It says that . is a incorrect syntax.

Comment: probably I aliased the CTE as "set" forgetting that this is an SQL reserved word.  Alias it as some other name and that should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! If i only would like to show all the vehicles where NameCount is 2 or bigger how should i do? Some kind of `having` statement?

Comment: I only have one last question. The name of the vehicles are shown 2 times now. Is there someway to only display it once instad of having shown twice?

Comment: It shouldn't do that as I posted it.  You must be selecting Name from both the set itself, and from the CountNames subquery.  Selecting only NameCount from the subquery in the main SELECT will solve this.

Comment: I don't really understand, could you please post it as a code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
Select Name, ECU, Identifier, Value,
       Max(Filetime) as "Filetime",
       (select count(*)
       from dbo.view_1 t2 
       where t2.Name = t1.Name and
             ECU ='EBS7' and 
             ((Identifier='88' and Value='2459579') or 
             (identifier ='87' and Value='2431629')) as cnt
from dbo.view_1 t1
where ECU ='EBS7' and 
      ((Identifier='88' and Value='2459579') or 
      (identifier ='87' and Value='2431629'))
group by Name, ECU, Identifier, Value
ORDER BY MAX(Name) ASC
```

Comment: Thank you but cnt shows wrong values. Agon the name Agon appears 2 times but cnt shows that it appears 561 times. For Aisa cnt is 564.

Comment: @AdnanHossain I forgot to include the other predicates in the `WHERE` clause of the subquery. Please check the edit I made.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Agon appears 39 times according to cnt and it goes on for the rest.

Comment: @AdnanHossain In that case there is an issue with your predicate. You should consider adding parentheses in the `WHERE` clause. Check the edit I made to see if it helps.

Comment: The edit helped and it shows right for many vehicles. But the is a little error. Some vehicles appears as cnt = 2 even though they are listed once.